# Executing a binary file from within a linux driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, executable, syslog, udev

I want to execute an executable file after the following lines are executed in usb driver.c file located [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/core/driver.c):

```
881         if (!retval)
882                 pr_info("%s: registered new device driver %s\n",
883                         usbcore_name, new_udriver->name);
```

In widows we have calls like `system` that can be used to call and execute a binary.  So I hope there is a similar option in Linux also.

**My log messages** are as under and I have mentioned where exactly I would like to execute the binary:

```
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.027 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.027 2014] U-Boot SPL 2014.01 (May 12 2014 - 16:08:58)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.027 2014] mmc boot
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.074 2014] reading fpga.bin
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.308 2014] zynq_align_dma_buffer: Bitstream is not swapped(1) - swap it
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.573 2014] reading system.dtb
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.589 2014] spl: error reading image system.dtb, err - -1
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.589 2014] reading u-boot.img
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.589 2014] reading u-boot.img
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.651 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.651 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.651 2014] U-Boot 2014.01 (May 12 2014 - 16:08:58)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.651 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.651 2014] I2C:   ready
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.651 2014] Memory: ECC disabled
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.651 2014] DRAM:  1 GiB
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] MMC:   zynq_sdhci: 0
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] Using default environment
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] In:    serial
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] Out:   serial
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] Err:   serial
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] Net:   Gem.e000b000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.667 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] Device: zynq_sdhci
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] Manufacturer ID: 2
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] OEM: 544d
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] Name: SA02G 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] Tran Speed: 50000000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] Rd Block Len: 512
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] SD version 3.0
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] High Capacity: No
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] Capacity: 1.8 GiB
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] Bus Width: 4-bit
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.729 2014] reading uEnv.txt
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.745 2014] ** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.745 2014] Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
        [Mon May 12 18:33:00.745 2014] reading uImage
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.073 2014] 3588280 bytes read in 322 ms (10.6 MiB/s)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.073 2014] reading devicetree.dtb
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.088 2014] 6804 bytes read in 19 ms (349.6 KiB/s)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.104 2014] reading uramdisk.image.gz
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014] 5310018 bytes read in 470 ms (10.8 MiB/s)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014] ## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 03000000 ...
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014]    Image Name:   Linux-3.13.0-xilinx-dirty
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014]    Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014]    Data Size:    3588216 Bytes = 3.4 MiB
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014]    Load Address: 00008000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014]    Entry Point:  00008000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.603 2014]    Verifying Checksum ... OK
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.665 2014] ## Loading init Ramdisk from Legacy Image at 02000000 ...
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.665 2014]    Image Name:   
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.665 2014]    Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.665 2014]    Data Size:    5309954 Bytes = 5.1 MiB
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.665 2014]    Load Address: 00000000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.665 2014]    Entry Point:  00000000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.665 2014]    Verifying Checksum ... OK
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.743 2014] ## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02a00000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.743 2014]    Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2a00000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.743 2014]    Loading Kernel Image ... OK
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.790 2014]    Loading Ramdisk to 1faef000, end 1ffff602 ... OK
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.821 2014]    Loading Device Tree to 1faea000, end 1faeea93 ... OK
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.821 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.821 2014] Starting kernel ...
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.821 2014] 
        [Mon May 12 18:33:01.837 2014] Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.165 2014] [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.165 2014] [    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-xilinx-dirty (root@zaidi) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-40) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 12 16:37:39 IST 2014
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.165 2014] [    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=18c5387d
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.165 2014] [    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.165 2014] [    0.000000] Machine model: Xilinx Zynq
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.165 2014] [    0.000000] bootconsole [earlycon0] enabled
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.165 2014] [    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.274 2014] [    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 8 pages/cpu @c143f000 s10688 r8192 d13888 u32768
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.274 2014] [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 260624
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.274 2014] [    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyPS0,115200n8 root=/dev/ram rw initrd=0x00800000,16M earlyprintk mtdparts=physmap-flash.0:512K(nor-fsbl),512K(nor-u-boot),5M(nor-linux),9M(nor-user),1M(nor-scratch),-(nor-rootfs)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.274 2014] [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.289 2014] [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.289 2014] [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.508 2014] [    0.000000] Memory: 1021760K/1048576K available (4857K kernel code, 310K rwdata, 1708K rodata, 198K init, 5345K bss, 26816K reserved, 270336K highmem)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.508 2014] [    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.508 2014] [    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.508 2014] [    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.508 2014] [    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xf0000000 - 0xff000000   ( 240 MB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.508 2014] [    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xef800000   ( 760 MB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.508 2014] [    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.523 2014] [    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.523 2014] [    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0671828   (6567 kB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.523 2014] [    0.000000]       .init : 0xc0672000 - 0xc06a39c0   ( 199 kB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.523 2014] [    0.000000]       .data : 0xc06a4000 - 0xc06f1ad0   ( 311 kB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.523 2014] [    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc06f1adc - 0xc0c2a1b0   (5346 kB)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.555 2014] [    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.555 2014] [    0.000000]     RCU lockdep checking is enabled.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.555 2014] [    0.000000]     Dump stacks of tasks blocking RCU-preempt GP.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.555 2014] [    0.000000]     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.555 2014] [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.570 2014] [    0.000000] ps7-slcr mapped to f0004000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.570 2014] [    0.000000] zynq_clock_init: clkc starts at f0004100
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.570 2014] [    0.000000] Zynq clock init
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.586 2014] [    0.000000] sched_clock: 32 bits at 333MHz, resolution 3ns, wraps every 12884901885ns
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.586 2014] [    0.000000] ps7-ttc #0 at f0006000, irq=43
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.601 2014] [    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.601 2014] [    0.000000] Lock dependency validator: Copyright (c) 2006 Red Hat, Inc., Ingo Molnar
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_SUBCLASSES:  8
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCK_DEPTH:          48
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_KEYS:        8191
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000] ... CLASSHASH_SIZE:          4096
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_ENTRIES:     16384
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_CHAINS:      32768
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000] ... CHAINHASH_SIZE:          16384
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000]  memory used by lock dependency info: 3695 kB
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [    0.000000]  per task-struct memory footprint: 1152 bytes
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.648 2014] [   12.877213] Calibrating delay loop... 1325.46 BogoMIPS (lpj=6627328)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.679 2014] [   12.877220] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.695 2014] [   12.877221] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.711 2014] [   12.877223] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.711 2014] [   12.877224] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.711 2014] [   12.877225] Setting up static identity map for 0x49ad18 - 0x49ad70
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.726 2014] [   12.877226] L310 cache controller enabled
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.726 2014] [   12.877227] l2x0: 8 ways, CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x72460000, Cache size: 512 kB
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.929 2014] [   12.877242] CPU1: Booted secondary processor
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.929 2014] [   12.877256] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.929 2014] [   12.877256] Brought up 2 CPUs
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.929 2014] [   12.877258] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.929 2014] [   12.877259] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.929 2014] [   12.877260] devtmpfs: initialized
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.945 2014] [   12.877262] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.960 2014] [   12.877264] regulator-dummy: no parameters
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.960 2014] [   12.877265] NET: Registered protocol family 16
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.960 2014] [   12.877266] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.976 2014] [   12.877268] cpuidle: using governor ladder
        [Mon May 12 18:33:02.976 2014] [   12.877269] cpuidle: using governor menu
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.007 2014] [   12.877273] syscon f8000000.ps7-slcr: regmap [mem 0xf8000000-0xf8000fff] registered
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.023 2014] [   12.877274] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.023 2014] [   12.877276] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.038 2014] [   12.877277] zynq-ocm f800c000.ps7-ocmc: ZYNQ OCM pool: 256 KiB @ 0xf0080000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.085 2014] [   12.877287] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.101 2014] [   12.877288] vgaarb: loaded
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.101 2014] [   12.877289] SCSI subsystem initialized



        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.116 2014] [   12.877290] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.116 2014] [   12.877291] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.116 2014] [   12.877291] usbcore: registered new device driver usb



    /**************************** EXECUTE BINARY HERE ************************/

    /**************************** EXECUTE BINARY HERE ************************/

    /**************************** EXECUTE BINARY HERE ************************/

    /**************************** EXECUTE BINARY HERE ************************/

        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.132 2014] [   12.877293] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.132 2014] [   12.877293] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.147 2014] [   12.877294] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.147 2014] [   12.877295] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.147 2014] [   12.877297] PTP clock support registered
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.163 2014] [   12.877297] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.179 2014] [   12.877300] DMA-API: preallocated 4096 debug entries
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.179 2014] [   12.877301] DMA-API: debugging enabled by kernel config
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.179 2014] [   12.877301] Switched to clocksource arm_global_timer
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.241 2014] [   12.877310] NET: Registered protocol family 2
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.241 2014] [   12.877311] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.257 2014] [   12.877313] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 6, 294912 bytes)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.257 2014] [   12.877314] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.272 2014] [   12.877315] TCP: reno registered
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.272 2014] [   12.877316] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 40960 bytes)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.288 2014] [   12.877317] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 40960 bytes)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.288 2014] [   12.877318] NET: Registered protocol family 1
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.319 2014] [   12.877319] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.319 2014] [   12.877320] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.319 2014] [   12.877321] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.319 2014] [   12.877322] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.319 2014] [   12.877323] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.319 2014] [   12.877324] rootfs image is not initramfs (no cpio magic); looks like an initrd
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.366 2014] [   12.877331] Freeing initrd memory: 5184K (dfaef000 - dffff000)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.381 2014] [   12.877332] hw perfevents: enabled with ARMv7 Cortex-A9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.397 2014] [   12.877335] bounce pool size: 64 pages
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.397 2014] [   12.877336] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.413 2014] [   12.877338] msgmni has been set to 1477
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.428 2014] [   12.877339] io scheduler noop registered
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.428 2014] [   12.877339] io scheduler deadline registered
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.428 2014] [   12.877340] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.459 2014] [   12.877343] dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma: unable to set the seg size
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.459 2014] [   12.877344] dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-2364208
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.459 2014] [   12.877345] dma-pl330 f8003000.ps7-dma:     DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-4 Num_Events-16
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.475 2014] [   12.877347] e0001000.serial: ttyPS1 at MMIO 0xe0001000 (irq = 82, base_baud = 3124999) is a xuartps
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.475 2014] [   12.877349] xdevcfg f8007000.ps7-dev-cfg: ioremap 0xf8007000 to f0068000
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.506 2014] [   12.877355] brd: module loaded
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.522 2014] [   12.877358] loop: module loaded
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.553 2014] [   12.877360] zynq-qspi e000d000.ps7-qspi: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.553 2014] [   12.877361] zynq-qspi e000d000.ps7-qspi: at 0xE000D000 mapped to 0xF006A000, irq=51
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.569 2014] [   12.877364] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 2.3.2-k
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.569 2014] [   12.877365] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2013 Intel Corporation.
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.584 2014] [   12.877366] libphy: XEMACPS mii bus: probed
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.600 2014] [   12.877367] mdio_bus e000b000: cannot get PHY at address 7
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.600 2014] [   12.877368] xemacps e000b000.ps7-ethernet: pdev->id -1, baseaddr 0xe000b000, irq 54
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.600 2014] [   12.877370] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.615 2014] [   12.877371] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.615 2014] [   12.877372] zynq-dr e0002000.ps7-usb: Unable to init USB phy, missing?
        [Mon May 12 18:33:03.631 2014] [   12.877373] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[Mon May 12 18:33:03.787 2014] [   12.877400] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[Mon May 12 18:33:03.803 2014] [   12.877205] TCP: cubic registered
[Mon May 12 18:33:03.803 2014] [   12.877206] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[Mon May 12 18:33:03.803 2014] [   12.877206] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[Mon May 12 18:33:03.818 2014] [   12.877207] bootconsole [earlycon0] disabled
```

Sorry for some confusion (my Id got swapped with my collegue).

I am running linux on embedded system with a volatile file system. So I will not be able to retain any changes in /etc/syslog.config  (if you are asking me to study about syslog).

Also I could not find syslog related file in the source code. Though I found one file with following contents:

```
#define SYSLOG_ACTION_CLEAR          5
/* Disable printk's to console */
#define SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_OFF    6
/* Enable printk's to console */
#define SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_ON     7
/* Set level of messages printed to console */
#define SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_LEVEL  8
/* Return number of unread characters in the log buffer */
#define SYSLOG_ACTION_SIZE_UNREAD    9
/* Return size of the log buffer */
#define SYSLOG_ACTION_SIZE_BUFFER   10

#define SYSLOG_FROM_CALL 0
#define SYSLOG_FROM_FILE 1

int do_syslog(int type, char __user *buf, int count, bool from_file);

#endif /* _LINUX_SYSLOG_H */
```

at `/include/linux/syslog.h`

But I am not getting any clue how to run the binary from here.

I treid running `exec`  alsao but is also not getting through.

Comment: `system()` exists also on unix as well, but is a userspace libc api call, you can't use that in kernel mode driver. Just as you can't use that also from windows.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-user-space-apps/index.html?ca=drs looks promising.

Comment: @PeterHorvath so in kernel mode driver any option?

Comment: No, you shouldn't write or modify a kernel driver for that, it were enough to play a little bit with your syslog daemon or with your udev configs. With most syslog daemon, you can call a binary if a such kernel log event is coming. And with udev, you can do something if a such device (with a given vendorid) appears.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Could u please give an answer with a sample code  to call binary using syslog daemon or udev?

Comment: No, it were offtopic (this is a question about a kernelmode programming solution). Read my answer carefully, and ask a new question after that.

Comment: You started to integrate practically new questions into your already answered question. And did you googled for the udev and syslog configuration? No. You want answers, but you don't work and don't upvote. You want practically not answers, but to let others to make your job. It is unthinkable evil.

Comment: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/315/2465 "If the question is about an API that only programmers would encounter (e.g. the C string library functions, the Gtk object model, **the Linux kernel driver APIs,** …), it's **off-topic here** and should be asked on Stack Overflow instead (or migrated there if it's already been asked here)."

Answer (score 5):

`system()` exists also on unixes as well, but is a userspace libc api call, and you can't use that in kernel mode driver. This is the case on windows as well. If a driver starts a binary executable, it uses different api calls for that on both systems.

It is possible to start a binary executable on linux, the best example is, when the kernel starts `/sbin/init` during boot.

Starting a process from kernelmode is possible with the `do_execve()` api call, which you can see that [`init/main.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/main.c?id=refs/tags/v3.15-rc5) in the kernel source.

Next to this I see 2 (and IMHO, much better) options to start a binary in this case:

1. It was a kernel messages, which are catched by the system logging daemons. These daemons are mostly possible to do something (for example, run your script) if a message matching a given regexp happens. Your best option for a such syslog daemon were (imho) syslog-ng or rsyslog.
2. There is the infrastructure named `udev`, which is a core component of practically all newer linux distributions. What udev does: practically watches for the changes of the device tree of your computer, and in case of any change (i.e. if a new usb device with vendor:modelid plugged in) will do what it was configured to. (Initializes device drivers, *calls external binaries*, loads alternate modules, etc.)

In your place I did (2), although the configuration of udev a little bit complex and not really well documented. With a syslog scripting you do this faster, although it weren't so beautiful solution.

I am nearly sure, that you don't need kernel mode programming to reach your goal.

Comment: I updated my question above. Also in my actual application I will not be putting any file system (neither intirmafs nor any other file system). /sbin/init appears come after mounting file system (I have seen these folders part of initrmafs.cpio), which may not be accesible to me since I am not using it.

Comment: @gpuguy No. You started to integrate practically new questions into your already answered question. And did you googled for the udev and syslog configuration? No. You want answers, but you don't work and don't upvote. You want practically not answers, but to let others to make your job. It is unthinkable evil.